# Get heart rate from BLE device on Windows 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows, exception, unity-game-engine, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing a companion app for my Unity game but I need to access data about the user's heart rate from a Mio Alpha Watch using Bluetooth Low Energy. I looked through the example project (C#) in:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Bluetooth-Generic-5a99ef95

The app recognizes the heart monitor but once I click on it and it says "waiting for device to send data..", it gives me an error "ERROR: Accessing your device failed. Incorrect function. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007001)"

Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Just because the product has BLE doesn't mean you can talk to it. Some devices require authorization and authenticarion bexause the manufacturer locked it down. Is this device open to developers?

Comment: I don't believe so. But I got it to work on Mac OSX using a plugin from the Unity store: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/8497  . Also, I've seen that an indie studio was able to do it using a Mio LINK watch that connects to a companion app they developed.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to start with Mio Link and node.js? :D There are frameworks, which support BLE, but they work only with ios and android. :S

Comment: I am not very proficient when it comes to JS but there is a JS example project in the link I posted. It was very helpful for me to start with when I was developing it using C#. Should be very similar as far as I know

Comment: @ChaosEmperor93 Did you find a solution on windows?

Comment: @Dinesh go to the link below:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30161845/unity-delay-in-sending-the-current-value-when-using-sockets/30162006?noredirect=1#comment48520114_30162006